# Is the Invoke Disaster feat's increase to a Storm druid's Focus Points redundant, since druids can never have more than 3 FP?

Tags: feats, druid, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

I'm playing Pathfinder 2e.

A [Storm druid](https://pf2.d20pfsrd.com/class/druid/#Storm) has a 2 FPs (focus points) initially. They get +1 FP from the [Wind Caller](https://pf2.d20pfsrd.com/class/druid/#Wind_Caller_Feat_8) feat, and another +1 FP from the [Invoke Disaster](https://pf2.d20pfsrd.com/class/druid/#Invoke_Disaster_Feat_18) feat, for a total of 4.

However, according to the [Druidic Order](https://pf2.d20pfsrd.com/class/druid/#Druidic_Order) feature, your focus pool can never hold more than 3 points. Thus, the +1 FP from Invoke Disaster is impossible.

Am I missing something, or am I right in thinking that the increase from Invoke Disaster is redundant because it will never actually affect the focus pool?

Comment: @ArtemStarostin Would you like me to have a crack at editing this into a form that's suitable for the site?

Comment: @John Clifford yes

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not redundant. A druid who starts as a member of an order which doesn't grant extra focus points (such as the [Animal](https://2e.aonprd.com/DruidicOrders.aspx?ID=1) and [Wild](https://2e.aonprd.com/DruidicOrders.aspx?ID=4) orders) can still gain access to the Invoke Disaster feat by first taking the [Order Explorer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=319) and [Wind Caller](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=334) feats. The resultant druid will have 1 focus point for being a druid, 1 focus point for the Wind Caller feat, and 1 focus point for Invoke Disaster, reaching their maximum pool size of 3 with no "wasted" increases.

A non-druid character with an existing 1 point focus pool who took the [Druid Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=701) multiclass feat and chose the Storm Druid order could do something similar, taking the Wind Caller and Invoke Disaster feats to gain a total pool size of 3.

Comment: I did wonder if there were effects that allowed you to take Storm Druid feats without actually being one, good answer.

This does mean that Invoke Disaster is pointless for an actual Storm Druid though, right? (well, they still get Storm Lord but in terms of the FP increase)

Comment: Yes, it appears that an actual Storm druid benefits less from Invoke Disaster than anyone else. Though it is still a pretty impressive spell.